# Any better solutions to an avatar command? -- Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have already made a working avatar command, but it isn't working with the user id in larger servers.

Here is my current code:

```py
@bot.command(brief='dev',usage="test", description="a testing command")
async def test(ctx, user): 
    x = user.isdigit()
    if x:
        user = await bot.fetch_user(user)
        print(user.name)
        print(user.avatar_url)
    else:
        user = user.replace('<@!','')
        user = user.replace('>','')
        print(user)
        user = await bot.fetch_user(user)
        print(user.name)
        print(user.avatar_url)
```

This works, but im wondering if theres a better way to do this, using `user:discord.User` is not an option since it fails to find via id. Also im not looking for anyone to write it for me, an example or an link is fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, using `user: discord.User` does not work because you are trying to fetch the `discord.User` object from an already `discord.User` object. Although I would recommend you to use `discord.Member`, as this ensures it belongs to the current guild so you can fetch his avatar.

Then, using `user: discord.Member` you do not need those ugly `user.replace('<@!','')` statements that could occasionate your function to not work for certain users.

I would also recommend you to not use `bot.fetch_user` in the future since that is a direct API call and there are better ways than doing it, like `bot.get_user`.

Your function could be as simple as this, which should work fine for any guild:

```py
@bot.command(brief='dev',usage="test", description="a testing command")
async def test(ctx, user : discord.Member=None): 
    if user:
        print(user.name)
        print(user.avatar_url)
```